# __DoPostback posts back the values of disabled controls when doing a partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I have a form which, for the sake of isolating the problem, has about a dozen plain HTML checkboxes (not WebControls), all of which are *disabled*.  They are inside an `UpdatePanel`.

I have a link which calls

> `__doPostBack('a-control','my-custom-argument');`

Depending on the first argument I supply, the page may do a full `postback` or a partial one.

When I do a full `postback`, none of the checkbox values are submitted in the post (because they are disabled).  This is the *normal* and thus *desired* behavior.

However, when it does a partial `postback`, the script collects all of the values from my checkboxes and submits them, without indicating which ones were disabled, which breaks my code.

It's annoying and I would like it to behave consistently.  Is there anyway to tell the .NET javascript handler to work the way the rest of the world does and *not* `postback` the values of *disabled* HTML form elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest two options:

1) You can remove the `name` attribute of disabled controls with JavaScript just before doing postback.

2) Override `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormSubmit` with corrected version of code. Just copy implementation from `MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js`, add a handling for the `disabled` attribute and attach the corrected function to the existing PageRequestManager object:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormSubmit = function...

Then register this JS block as startup script. It's important to get a correct order of rendered script blocks. I do a similar thing in my subclass of ScriptManager:

```
protected override void OnResolveScriptReference(ScriptReferenceEventArgs e) {
    base.OnResolveScriptReference(e);

    if (e.Script.Name.StartsWith("MicrosoftAjax"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "My patch", MyPatchJs, true);
}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me. According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12) disabled inputs should *not* be submitted with the form.

Here is my complete test page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" EnableViewState="false" EnableEventValidation="false" Trace="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Test disabled checkboxes</title>
    <script>
    initState = false;
    function disableCheckboxes(disabled) {
        document.getElementById('foo').disabled = disabled;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <input runat="server" type="checkbox" id="foo" name="foo" checked="checked" /> Foo
            <asp:Button ID="Inside" runat="server" Text="Submit Inside UpdatePanel" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button ID="Outside" runat="server" Text="Submit Outside UpdatePanel" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="disableCheckboxes(initState=!initState)">Toggle checkboxes</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open up Fiddler and the test page.
2. Click "Submit Outside UpdatePanel" (triggers a normal Postback). Note in Fiddler the value `"foo=on"` is submitted in the POST body.
3. Click "Toggle checkboxes" to disable the checkbox.
4. Click "Submit Outside UpdatePanel" again. Note the parameter `"foo"` is omitted from the POST body. This is expected.
5. Click "Submit Inside UpdatePanel" (triggers a partial Postback). Note the value `"foo=on"` is present in the POST body, even though it *should have been omitted*

---

The bug appears to be in both **`MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js`** and **`MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`** (and the `.debug` counterparts of each):

```
if ((type === 'text') ||
    (type === 'password') ||
    (type === 'hidden') ||
    (((type === 'checkbox') || (type === 'radio')) && element.checked)) {
        formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(name));
        formBody.append('=');
        formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(element.value));
        formBody.append('&');
}
```

The `disabled` attribute on the element being serialized is completely ignored, going against the spec and de-facto behaviour of form submission implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net the form tag has the submitdisabledcontrols attribute, which defaults to false.  You can at least make things behave consistently if you set it to true.